# Referencing column labels when creating new variables in R

Tags: r, reference, label, col

I've scraped a data frame into R like so:

```
page.201702050atl = read_html("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201702050atl.htm")
comments.201702050atl = page.201702050atl %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//comment()")
team.stats.201702050atl = comments.201702050atl[27] %>% html_text() %>% read_html() %>% html_node("#team_stats") %>% html_table()
> team.stats.201702050atl
                                NWE           ATL
1         First Downs            37            17
2        Rush-Yds-TDs      25-104-2      18-104-1
3   Cmp-Att-Yd-TD-INT 43-63-466-2-1 17-23-284-2-0
4        Sacked-Yards          5-24          5-44
5      Net Pass Yards           442           240
6         Total Yards           546           344
7        Fumbles-Lost           1-1           1-1
8           Turnovers             2             1
9     Penalties-Yards          4-23          9-65
10   Third Down Conv.          7-14           1-8
11  Fourth Down Conv.           1-1           0-0
12 Time of Possession         40:31         23:27
> str(team.stats.201702050atl)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
 $    : chr  "First Downs" "Rush-Yds-TDs" "Cmp-Att-Yd-TD-INT" "Sacked-Yards" ...
 $ NWE: chr  "37" "25-104-2" "43-63-466-2-1" "5-24" ...
 $ ATL: chr  "17" "18-104-1" "17-23-284-2-0" "5-44" ...
```

As you can see, R scrapes this table with the 2nd and 3rd column already labeled. I would like to give these columns generic lables and move `c("", "NWE", "ATL")` into the table itself so that I can work with it. Additionally, I'd like to fill that empty cell, when I move the row into the table, with text of my own. In other words, I want to end up with something that looks like:

```
> team.stats.201702050atl.a
                       V1            V2            V3
    1                  Tm           NWE           ATL
    2         First Downs            37            17
    3        Rush-Yds-TDs      25-104-2      18-104-1
    4   Cmp-Att-Yd-TD-INT 43-63-466-2-1 17-23-284-2-0
    5        Sacked-Yards          5-24          5-44
    6      Net Pass Yards           442           240
    7         Total Yards           546           344
    8        Fumbles-Lost           1-1           1-1
    9           Turnovers             2             1
    10     Penalties-Yards          4-23          9-65
    11   Third Down Conv.          7-14           1-8
    12  Fourth Down Conv.           1-1           0-0
    13 Time of Possession         40:31         23:27
```

I know I could do something like:

```
team.stats.201702050atl.a = as.data.frame(t(team.stats.201702050atl))
team.stats.201702050atl.a$r1 = c("Tm", "NWE", "ATL")
team.stats.201702050atl = as.data.frame(t(team.stats.201702050atl.a))
```

...but how do I get R to reference the column labels in team.stats.201702050atl$V2 and team.stats.201702050atl$V3 directly without explicitly typing them out? And, how do I do so while inserting original text of my own in the first column of that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to transpose, you can use rbind to add the vector of columns names as a row, for example:

```
team.stats.201702050atl2 <- rbind(c("Tm", "NWE", "ATL"), team.stats.201702050atl)
```

Or directly rbind the column names using colnames, and add the missing "Tm" value:

```
team.stats.201702050atl2 <- rbind(colnames(team.stats.201702050atl), team.stats.201702050atl)
team.stats.201702050atl2[1,1] <- "Tm"
```

See `?colnames` and `?rownames`to reference column and row names.  You can for instance reference a specific column name by indexing.  For example: `colnames(team.stats.201702050atl2)[1]` or `colnames(team.stats.201702050atl2)[2:3]`, and this gives another approach:

```
team.stats.201702050atl2 <- rbind(c("Tm", colnames(team.stats.201702050atl)[2:3]), team.stats.201702050atl)
```

Or a variant:

```
team.stats.201702050atl2 <- rbind(c("Tm", colnames(team.stats.201702050atl)[2:ncol(team.stats.201702050atl)]), team.stats.201702050atl)
```

Finally, assign new column names using colnames:

```
colnames(team.stats.201702050atl2) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
```